# Android map showing only grids not showing any map view

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I am developing small android application in which I want to show users current location on map. For that reason I am using Google map API. I follow all required setup for getting map api key. I get default key store at location <.android/debug.keystore>. I get all required values from that keys like SHA1 key and MD 5 key.Then on Google API console I get API key by using SHA1+package_name. I also enable Google map API v2 service.

Now on my project side I did following thing.

```
// in main.xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/myLocationText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".WhereAmI" />

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/myMapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="AIzaSyD6EHgxObm01ooCF9DsMzOppJbNp8O2_j4"
    />

</LinearLayout>


// In manifest file 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>

//mapactivity..........
public class mapview extends MapActivity {

    private MapController mapController;

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
    }

    private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        updateWithNewLocation(location);

        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
        {

        }
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
        {

        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
        Bundle extras) 
        {

        }
        };
        LocationManager locationManager;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    MapView myMapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.myMapView);
    mapController = myMapView.getController();
    myMapView.setSatellite(true);
    myMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapController.setZoom(17);

    //LocationManager locationManager;
    String svcName = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(svcName);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setSpeedRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    //dis(provider);
    //Location l = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    Location l = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    updateWithNewLocation(l);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2000, 10, locationListener);

    }


    private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) 
    {
        TextView myLocationText;
        myLocationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myLocationText);
        String latLongString = "No location found";
        String addressString = " No address found";
        //Toast.makeText(this, "inside update location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (location != null) 
        {
            double lat = location.getLatitude();
            double lng = location.getLongitude();
            latLongString = "Lat:" + lat + "\nLong:" + lng;
            Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            Double geoLat = location.getLatitude()*1E6;
            Double geoLng = location.getLongitude()*1E6;
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(geoLat.intValue(),geoLng.intValue());
            mapController.animateTo(point);

            try {
                List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
                sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
                sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
                sb.append(address.getCountryName());
                }
                addressString = sb.toString();
                } catch (IOException e) {}

                myLocationText.setText("Your Current Position is:\n" +
                latLongString + "\n\n" + addressString);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() 
    {
    super.onDestroy();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    }

}
```

Now my problem is that when I run this application on emulator or device it gives me proper coordinates and location but it not showing map view. It shows only gray grid view. I know there are lot of duplicates question are there regarding same issue but still i am not able o get out of this problem. I also create custom debug key and use SHA1 value of that key but no change in output. Is there any solution to solve this problem...
Need help...
Thank you...

Comment: is the speed of internet good enough to download map tiles ?

Comment: I wait for long time but its not working...  :(

Comment: It gives me error **Couldn't get connection factory client**

Comment: Did you try it on a reaL DEVICE ? looks like this is a bug of the emulator. 

Have a look here 
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8816

Comment: Yeah I tried it on real device as well on emulator but giving same output. On api console I am enabling service google map API v2. as well on few location read use MD5 key and at location SHA1. If use md5 value then it not accepting that value. accepts only SHA1 value. Is it problem in API key?

Comment: yes. key of v1 dosent work in v2. look [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key) for more info. If you are using an API key of API v2, try using fragment according to [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#add_a_map)

Comment: Thanks rajat for reply. But v1 now deprecated. That mean I have to use v2. thanks for help.. I will try your solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unable to download the map, there might be one of the two problems :

1) you are  using a version of API that is deprecated. 
2) you do not have a speedy internet connection.

The code you have shown uses API v1, and you use a key of API v2. I am not sure if that works but using API v2 with a key of v2 definitely works. Look here [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key).
Also use a fragment instead of a Mapview.

Also try it on a real device, because emulator has some issues as shown [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8816)

Comment: Hi rajat tried to follow your giving solution. But When I tried to add google play lib into my project it gives red mark on (not cross) my android project. and when I tried to run my project it gives me error that your project having some error fix that error. But my project not having any error. Even I tried to run sample from android sdk folder sample for mapdemo but same problem occurred with that also.

Comment: I follow this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro#sample_code) but not able to run my project. My project not having error. But still its not working... :(

Comment: @nilkash start from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) . Skip the sample. Start from scratch. Copy android-support-v4.jar to the libs folder of your project.

Comment: thank you rajat but I follow that one also but same result.In project properties java build path -> libraries -> android dependencies it gives me error for google-play-service_lib.jar-<path to google-play-service_lib>/bin(missing)

Comment: [here is my project set up](http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/4572/screenshotfrom201301041.png)

Comment: hye rajat I got the solution but I don't know whether its right solution or not. It gives me error in the dependencies. It unable to find out google-play-service_lib.jar. So what I did I copied google-play-service.jar and google-play-service.properties file from lib folder to bin in library. and clean and build library in eclipse. It generate google-play-service_lib.jar file after build in bin folder.

Comment: After that in main project I removed old library and include new one and not its working fine. Now it not showing me any dependencies error and also running properly on my device.. I don't know what is the main reason behind this problem. But right now it's working for me ... Thank you for your good support... :)